# Reading a zip file(folder) and writing it in the destination

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a zip file out of a folder and reading it using jetpack.createReadstream with highWaterMark as 1 * 1024 on the local peer. I'm listening on data event and sending the data to the other peer (remote) and created a writeStream over there. The data being read is buffer and I'm able to pass the data successfully to the other peer using webrtc. When I put the buffer into writestream, it created the zip file but did not write anything into it.

[image: Reading a zip file and sending data to other peer]

[image: The data that was read[][2]]

![Write stream created on the remote peer[][3][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7NnG.png)

[image: Writing data into the writestream]

The writestream created a zip file at the destination but did not write the data.

Comment: please add the code here, don't post screenshots of the code

Comment: Sorry for that. I'm new at posting questions in stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple fix when creating my writestream. I just added options object with flags: 'a' (append) and that worked out.

```js
 // Create write stream
  var writeStream = jetpack.createWriteStream(writePath, {autoClose: true, flags: 'a'});

  // Open write stream
  writeStream.on('open', (e) => {
    this.channelMap.set(msg.channel, {
      writeStream,
      tracker: {
        stat : msg.stat,
        received: 0
      }
    });
```